# Send phone audio output to PC without affecting phone mic?

Tags: usb, audio, microphone, broadcast

I want to be a game streamer and use my phone to play mobile games. Therefore, I need to send my phone's sounds to my PC. I found a tutorial that suggested using the 3.5mm headset jack and a USB sound card.

I tried that by plugging one of the ends into the USB sound card (mic jack) and the other end into my phone's 3.5mm jack.

The thing is, now my phone's mic is not functioning, and my phone will detect my PC's mic as its input mic. But the thing I need is my phone's sounds being sent as microphone input to my PC.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did the audio cable work? That is, did your phone's audio output go to your PC? If so, why are you worried about the phone's mic? Are you playing mobile games that involve voice chat or verbal commands?

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? Your phone's audio jack, by default, doesn't send what it's also picking up. You need some sort of passthrough audio setup on your phone if you wish to send what the mic is picking up out on the analog output.